# How to print an opencv terminal output to a webpage (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, hough-transform

Is it possible to get an opencv terminal output and print it to a web page? I would appreciate some help/advice, thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide a [minimum working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: opencv rarely prints out things on its own, so what exactly is the situation ? again, show, what you're doing, please

Comment: I have tried using flask, my program outputs the amount of circles it detects every 10 seconds using hough circles and time.sleep but i just can't get it to output to a web page, help would be really appreciated

Comment: I have used print(len(circles[0, :])) to print the amount of circles as a integer (to the terminal)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you're already using flask, it's probably just a matter of *returning a string* from your @route (instead of printing it to the terminal):

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    # ... some opencv code, calculating circles
    return 'We have %d circles !' % (len(circles[0, :]),)
```

Comment: I am very grateful as this has worked, however i would like to make it so it automatically updates every 10 seconds, i have the followng code:        def ball():
            print(len(circles[0, :]))
            time.sleep(10)                        Do you know how i can implement this?

Comment: or would it be better to find a way to reload flask automatically instead of using time.sleep?

Comment: I'll accept the answer as i realized i didn't put that in the question but i would really appreciate it if you could also tell me how to make flask automatically reload. Thanks!

Comment: flask works like: client request -> server response. so you have to make the *client* send requests. and any sleep() in your code is useless

Comment: Ahh, thank you very much.. shouldn't be too hard to find a solution.. I had been stuck with this for a few weeks now so I really appreciate your help. I'll stop bugging you now haha